# Running Android Tests setUp() method gets called multiple times

Tags: java, android, eclipse, junit4

I am creating a test suite for my android application and have this setUp method

```
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "TESTING_SUITE";
        public TestingMusicDAO musicDAO;
        public List<Song> songs;
        public Instrumentation instr;
        MusicService musicService;
    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        instr = this.getInstrumentation();
        Log.d(TAG_NAME, "Setting up testing songs");
        musicDAO = new TestingMusicDAO(instr.getContext());
        musicService = new MusicServiceImpl(musicDAO);
        musicDAO.getAllSongsFromFile();
        songs = musicDAO.getAllSongs();
        for(Song song : songs)
            Log.d( TAG_NAME, song.toString() );
     }
```

And then have these tests which are created by a python tool from a text file

```
public void test1() {
    List<Song> testPlaylist;
    String testArtist = ("The Beatles");
    String actualArtist = ("TheBeatles"); 
    testPlaylist = testingPlaySongsByKeyword(testArtist);
    if(testPlaylist.isEmpty()){
        fail("No Songs Were Found");
    } else {
        for( Song loopsongs : testPlaylist){
            if (!(loopsongs.getArtist().equals(actualArtist))){
                fail("Song Doesnt Contain the artist" + actualArtist + "... Contains ->" + loopsongs.getArtist());
            }
        }
   }
}
```

and every time one of these gets called the musicDAO is regenerated. How can I stop the setup method from being called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't.  The design of JUnit is that `setUp()` and `tearDown()` are done **once per test**.  If you want it done per class, do it in the constructor.  Just make sure that you don't alter anything inside the classes.  The reason for doing it once per test is to make sure all tests start with the same data.

Comment: So i would create a constructor of the test class?

Comment: THat's the only function I know of that would be run only once.  You're better off writing tests the way jUnit expects though-  it'll be less painful in the end.

Comment: Alright just painfully slow generated a database for each test

Comment: Instead of using the constructor, you could use `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` as Vikash already mentioned.

Comment: @vikash-kumar-verna 's answer is the correct answer. In JUnit4 Ctor is executed once for each test case, because I assume it creates a new object for each test case.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`@BeforeClass`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) and [`@AfterClass`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/AfterClass.html) annotations from JUnit.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void test_setUp_Once(){
  // Code which you want to be executed only once
  createDb();
}

@AfterClass
public static void test_tearDown_Once(){
  // Code which you want to be executed only once
  deleteDb();
}
```

Note: You need to declare these methods `static` to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same basic problem. I want to be able to test the structure of my database, so I create it in the setUp method and delete it in the tearDown. Using the constructor wouldn't solve my need to delete the database once all my tests are executed, so I used some reentrant logic:

```
static int testsExecutedSoFar = 0;
static boolean isFirstRun = true;

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    if(isFirstRun){
        createDb();
        isFirstRun = false;
    }       
}

@Override
protected void tearDown() throws Exception{
    testsExecutedSoFar++;
    if (testsExecutedSoFar == totalNumberOfTestCases())
        deleteDb();     
}

private int totalNumberOfTestCases() {
    return countTestCases()+1; //have to add one for testandroidtestcasesetupproperly added by AndroidTestCase
}
```

The fields have to be static since JUnit creates a new instance of the class for each run. The magic 1 had to be added since AndroidTestCase adds it's own test (testandroidtestcasesetupproperly) to the test suite but it doesn't count towards the number returned by countTestCases().

A bit on the ugly side, but it did the trick.